# Flyway two migration files location

Tags: flyway

I have two locatoins for migration files.
 1. SQL files:  src/main/resources/db.migration.
 2. Java files: src/main/java/com.xx.yy.db.migration

I use this code:

```
location = classpath:db/migration/dev,com.xx.yy.db.migration

Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setLocations(location);
flyway.setInitOnMigrate(false);
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);

flyway.migrate();
```

It doesn't work.

It does work if I use only one (doesn't matter which one).

I tried:

classpath:db/migration/dev,classpath:com.xx.yy.db.migration  --> does not work.

classpath:db/migration/dev --> works

classpath:com.xx.yy.db.migration --> works

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Id

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

I fixed it by giving it an arrays of strings instead of one string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should put filesystem first, like:

flyway.setLocations( "filesystem:/home/../../db/migration/" );

So flyway will recognize your directory.